# Is executing 2 sql networks requests the only way to get the parent of child records without getting redundant data?

Tags: sql, join

It seems that there is no way to get the following result set from query:

Say there are two database tables that have a one-to-many relationship, like a teacher table and a student table where a teacher has many students and a student has 1 teacher (so the `student` table has a `teacher_id` column). What is the most efficient way of getting data? Currently, I see two options that have a weakness:

#### Method 1: Execute Two SQL Queries

1. Execute a query that gets all the students.
2. Get the unique teacher IDs from the students.
3. Query the teachers table to get the specific teachers.

The downside of this is that **2 queries were executed**. This becomes a network problem since 2 network requests have to be made from a client application.

#### Method 2: Execute A Join Query

1. Join the two tables to get the students joined with their teachers.
2. Parse the data to get those specific teachers.

The downside of this is that **each student** has **each column** of their teacher, even if the teacher is repeated for multiple students. Though the goal is to get the columns of the students and teachers, the problem is that the teachers will be listed multiple times. It becomes a waste. The worse case scenario is that all students have the same 1 teacher. That causes the 1 teacher to be listed multiple times even though I only wanted it once.

A close third option would be to use `group by` to group the students together according to their teachers. But then we don't have a way to get all the students.

Is there no way to get the child table and the parent table without executing 2 network request or parsing redundant, unneeded data?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the result of the join query, but with the teachers grouped somehow?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy Yes, keeping in mind that I still want the students who are under that teacher.

Comment: Depending on the database you are using, you could get a result set that allows lists, eg XML or JSON as an output. Or you could use a NoSQL, say a documented-oriented database like MongoDB to get JSON results. Standard relational database recordsets are rectangular in nature, so without returning a list element, there is a mathematical constraint forcing redundancy in the results, or two separate query result sets.

Comment: Can you please add expected output in your question?